# DateTime.ParseExact give the error: String was not recognized as a valid DateTime

Tags: c#, datetime, tryparse

I want to parse DateTime, here my code:

```
var datastring =p1.ItemArray[2].ToString();
var format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datastring,format,CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

p1 - is `DataRow`, in `p1.ItemArray[2]` I have value of DateTime

In watch `p1.ItemArray[2]` have this value : `"09/03/2012 00:00:00"` his type is `DateTime`

After parsing throws error: **String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.**

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could include the time in your format as it seems the string you are trying to parse contains the time:

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy hh:mm:ss";
```

Also I would recommend you using the [TryParseExact](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact.aspx) method as it provides a better defensive programming pattern instead of throwing exceptions.

Answer (score 2):

IMHO you should use

```
var datastring = p1.ItemArray[2].ToString();
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
var date = DateTime.ParseExact(datastring, format, CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

With `ParseExact` you must provide exact format of date contained in string

Answer (score 1):

Change this:

```
var format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
```

With this:

```
var format = "dd/MM/yyyy HH:mm:ss";
```

Comment: I want to compare with other variable that is in format "dd.MM.yyyy"

Comment: @Alex: it doesn't matter: convert the other "string date " in DateTime and then compare two dates!! If you need to compare dates, don't compare strings :)

Comment: @Alex What do you mean? Compare two DateTime structures or strings?

Answer (score 0):

because parseExact will expect to receive the same format that you specified which is "dd.MM.yyyy". You can try:

```
var format = "dd.MM.yyyy";
var datastring =p1.ItemArray[2].ToString(format);
```

Comment: method 'ToString' has 0 parameter tu it invoked with 1 argument

Answer (score 0):

Most probably due to the difference between your Server locale and the UI locale

One easier method will be to specify the globalization details in the web.config

like

```
<configuration>
   <system.web>
      <globalization culture="en-GB"/>
   </system.web>
</configuration>
```

OR in more detail

```
<globalization requestEncoding="utf-8" responseEncoding="utf-8" culture="en-GB" uiCulture="en-GB" />
```

But be sure this wont clash with your application in general